# something with one openflow controller and two openvswitch

Tags: openflow, openvswitch

I create a network like below

```
   host1:floodlight controller

                |

         L2 physical switch

                |

           /           \

host2:ovs1                host3:ovs2
```

every host has one network device

**host1:**  eno1(192.168.100.101)

**host2:**  config openvswitch br1(192.168.100.102) with eno1

**host3:**  config openvswitch br1(192.168.100.103) with eno1

**floodlight running on host1**: listen on 0.0.0.0:6653

When I don't set the ovs controller on host2 and host3, host2/host3 can ping host1 and host2 can ping host3

when I do set ovs controller on host2(/host3) and not set on host3(/host2), host2/host3 can ping host1 and host2 can ping host3

when I do set ovs controller on host2 and host3, host2 can ping host3, but host2/host3 can not ping host1

After checking the tcpdump on host2/host3, found that the icmp data packet alreay send and recv on eno1:

```
tcpdump -i eno1 icmp

....192.168.100.102 > 192.168.100.101....

....192.168.100.101 > 192.168.100.102....

....192.168.100.102 > 192.168.100.101....

....192.168.100.101 > 192.168.100.102....
```

Also found that the icmp data packet alreay send and not recv on br1

```
tcpdump -i br1 icmp

....192.168.100.102 > 192.168.100.101....

....192.168.100.102 > 192.168.100.101....
```

why?? my config have some error?